# Flask POST error is causing server to crash (ERROR in app: Exception on /Summarize [POST])

Tags: python, html, flask, deployment, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to build a simple webpage using Hugging Face Transformer to summarise data and deploy it however I am constantly running into this problem.

This is the app.py file I am running

```
import requests
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for
from flask import request as req


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/",methods=["GET","POST"])
def Index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/Summarize",methods=["GET","POST"])
def Summarize():
    if req.method== "POST":
        API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/facebook/bart-large-cnn"
        headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer <API-KEY>"}

        data=req.form["data"]

        maxL=int(req.form["maxL"])
        minL=maxL//4
        def query(payload):
            response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
            return response.json()

        output = query({
            "inputs":data,
            "parameters":{"min_length":minL,"max_length":maxL},
        })[0]
        
        return render_template("index.html",result=output["summary_text"])
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

This is the error that I am getting when I deploy the webpage

```
type here
ERROR in app: Exception on /Summarize [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hipprofessional/Downloads/Data-Summarization-master/app.py", line 25, in Summarize
    output = query({
             ^^^^^^^
KeyError: 0
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2023 23:03:18] "POST /Summarize HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Please let me know how I can go about fixing this and how I can relaunch it again and again for personal use

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nothing exists in the `output` list, hence the KeyError when attempting to access the 0<sup>th</sup> element.